# Is "char foo = 255" undefined behavior if char is signed?

Tags: c, gcc

The following doesn't give me any warning whatsoever when compiled with gcc 4.5.2 on x86 machine with Linux:

```
char foo = 255;
```

But when I use `-pedantic`, gcc says:

> warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion

The way gcc acts is a tad strange and it makes me doubt if I really understand what's going on in this assignment. I think that if `char` is 8 bit long on POSIX and it's signed by default, it can't hold `255`.

In C standard, it says that unsigned integer overflow results in overflow, but signed integer overflow is undefined. So is this assignment undefined behavior? And why does gcc act this way?

Comment: Somewhere I read that only real over-**flows** were UB and as such, the assignment operator didn't invoke undefined behavior, but I'm not sure. +1 for this question anyway.

Comment: But did you try to print `foo` after this? What value do you get?

Comment: The warning is just to let you know that the number won't be what you set it to, rather than warning about any undefined behaviour, but the more general question is interesting. My intuition says that it is undefined (since `foo` is signed, so it would be undefined at runtime), but I have no idea.

Comment: Read: [Warning : overflow in implicit constant conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095434/warning-overflow-in-implicit-constant-conversion)

Comment: According to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4934719/1180785 it is indeed undefined.

Comment: @Dave Which line in that answer does say it's undefined?

Comment: implementation-defined is not the same thing as undefined

Comment: @DennisMeng yeah, after seeing AndreyT's answer I've just spent the past couple of minutes researching exactly that distinction!

Comment: I will note that right-shifts are another "implementation-defined" thing. If that meant the same thing as "undefined" we'd all be completely screwed several times over.

Comment: @DennisMeng surely right-shifts of *unsigned* values are well defined?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant right-shifts for signed values.

Comment: @Smac89: printf("foo = %d\n", foo); shows "foo = -1"

Comment: @user1042840

If you do `printf("foo = %c\n", foo);`, you would see why it is undefined because it should print garbage

Comment: @Smac89: it prints `garbage' because there is no such sign in ASCII characters but you could use values like this to compose an Unicode character

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Summary: The result is implementation-defined and very likely to be `-1`, but it's complicated, at least in principle.

The rules regarding overflow are different for operators vs. conversions, and for signed types vs. unsigned types -- and the conversion rules changed between C90 and C99.

As of C90, overflow of an operator with signed integer operands ("overflow" meaning that the mathematical result cannot be represented in the expression's type) has undefined behavior. For unsigned integer operands, the behavior is well defined as the usual wraparound (strictly speaking the standard doesn't call this an "overflow"). But your declaration:

```
char foo = 255;
```

doesn't use any operators (the `=` is an initializer, not an assignment), so none of that applies in this case.

If type `char` can represent the value `255` (which is true either of plain `char` is unsigned or if `CHAR_BIT >= 9`), then of course the behavior is well defined. The `int` expression `255` is implicitly converted to `char`. (Since `CHAR_BIT >= 8`, it's not possible for this particular case to invoke unsigned wraparound.)

Otherwise, the conversion yields a result that can't be stored in a `char`.

As of C90, the result of the conversion is implementation-defined -- which means that it's guaranteed to set `foo` to *some* value within the range of type `char`, and you can determine what that value is by reading the implementation's documentation, which is required to tell you how the conversion works. (I've never seen an implementation where the stored value is anything other than `-1`, but any result is possible in principle.)

C99 changed the definition, so that an overflowing conversion to a signed type *either* yields an implementation-defined result *or* raises an implementation-defined signal.

If a compiler chooses to do the latter, then it must document which signal is raised.

So what happens if an implementation-defined signal is raised? Section 7.14 of the standard says:

> The complete set of signals, their semantics, and their default
>   handling is implementation-defined

It's not entirely clear (to me) what the range of possible behaviors for the "default handling" of signals is. In the worst case, I suppose such a signal could terminate the program. You *might or might not* be able to define a signal handler that catches the signal.

7.14 also says:

> If and when the function returns, if the value of sig is **SIGFPE**,
>   **SIGILL**, **SIGSEGV**, or any other implementation-defined value
>   corresponding to a computational exception, the behavior is undefined;
>   otherwise the program will resume execution at the point it was
>   interrupted.

but I don't *think* that applies, since an overflowing conversion is not a "computational exception" as the term is used here. (Unless the implementation-defined signal happens to be `SIGFPE`, `SIGILL`, or `SIGSEGV` -- but that would be silly).

So ultimately, if an implementation chooses to raise a signal in response to an overflowing conversion, the behavior (not just the result) is at least implementation-defined, and there might be circumstances in which it could be undefined. In any case, there doesn't seem to be any *portable* way to deal with such a signal.

In practice, I've never heard of an implementation that takes advantage of the new wording in C99. For all compilers I've heard of, the result of the conversion is implementation-defined -- and very probably yields what you'd expect from a 2's-complement truncation. (And I'm not at all convinced that this change in C99 was a good idea. If nothing else, it made this answer about 3 times as long as it would otherwise have needed to be.)

Comment: So this: "char foo = 255" is implementation defined on POSIX systems but in practice it comes down to wraparound. Is it the same for unsigned types such as in "unsigned int foo = 9999999999"? I know it wraprounds but is it also implementation defined? And also why does gcc warn obut "overflow" in char case with -pedantic mode if it's not an overflow what happens here?

Comment: It's actually not silly at all IMO for the signal to be `SIGFPE` - while most real-world systems don't raise a signal for integer overflow, they _do_ often raise one for integer division, and the one they raise is SIFGPE. Regardless of the fact that the name implies a _floating-point_ error. (Of course, the result of integer division is undefined behavior)

Comment: @user1042840: Conversion to unsigned types is defined by the standard; it effectively discards all but the low-order N bits of the result (though the standard defines the result in terms of arithmetic values, not bits). Why do you say it's not an overflow? (The C standard doesn't define that term.)

Comment: @ Keith Thompson: I was suggested by what Adam Rosenfield said: "Besides, there's no overflow occurring here -- all you have is an integer literal (255, of type int, which does not overflow) being converted to type char". But now I see that you were talking about how overflow is handled in conversions and expressions.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: So to sum up: 1. in conversions, signed overflow is implementation defined (or raises an implementation-defined signal in C99), unsigned overflow results in wraparound. 2. in operators, signed overflow is undefined behavior (described in section 6.5 in point 5) and unsigned behavior results in wraparound. Did I got it right?

Comment: @user1042840: Yes, that's it.

Comment: I suppose that raising a signal makes sense for interpreters, but it seems silly in a compiler.

Comment: @dmckee: I'm not sure how interpreter vs. compiler matters. Here's how I think of it: A signed-to-signed or unsigned-to-signed conversion whose result doesn't fit in the target type is very probably a programming error. *It would be nice* to have a consistent way to detect and handle such errors. Raising a signal might be such a way -- **if** you could write portable code that can catch the signal and do something sensible with it, sort of stripped-down version of exception handling. The clause that C99 added, "*or an implementation-defined signal is raised"*, doesn't do that. ...

Comment: ... If you know what signal to use for a given implementation, you might be able to do something with it, but such code would only work for that implementation. There isn't even a way for a program to query whether an implementation will raise a signal, or to find out which one. And it applies only to overflow on conversions; similar overflows on arithmetic operators are simply *undefined*. I think it was intended to provide an implementation-defined hook for overflow handling, something that didn't exist in C90, ...

Comment: ... but in practice I think it's just given programmers one more thing to worry about -- and it's something that, as far as I know, never happens in the real world anyway (because compilers haven't taken advantage of it). (Yeah, this is probably way too long for a comment.)

Comment: @KeithThompson PLease help me understand what you meant by "For unsigned integer operands, the behavior is well defined as the `usual wraparound`". What did you mean by *usual wraparound*?

Comment: @Geek: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.2.5p9: "A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow,
because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is
reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be
represented by the resulting type." The effect is that all but the low-order N bits of the result are discarded, where N is the width of the unsigned type. For example, if `UINT_MAX==65535`, then `UINT_MAX + 1 == 0`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Only computations involving unsigned operands *which are too large to be promoted to `int`* cannot overflow.  IMHO, there's no reason why the standard shouldn't specify that if the result of an integer operator other than `>>`, `/`, and `%` is cast or coerced to an unsigned type smaller than `int`, the computation will be performed as unsigned, and the operands will be cast or coerced likewise.  Such a rule would not change any defined behavior, and probably have no effect other than to guard against wacky "optimizations", but IMHO such guarding would be a good thing.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Unfortunately, the Standard presently allows compilers given an expression like `uint16_t x=y*z;` to behave in weird and wacky fashion if the product is too large to fit in an `int` even though in all cases where behavior is defined the standard would require that it be computed mod 65536.

Comment: @supercat: There are no arithmetic operations on integer types narrower than `int`. Any such operands are promoted to `int` or to `unsigned int`. I agree that it's annoying that `uint16_t x = y * z;` can overflow. As a workaround, you can change it to `uint16_t x = (unsigned)x * (unsigned)y;`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: *In all cases where behavior is defined by the standard*, and probably all where it's usefully defined by a compiler, *period*, the behavior will be the same as if performed on the shorter type, or on `unsigned int`.  Further, except on platforms which are faster to perform math on `int` than `unsigned int` *and* do not handle signed overflows in modular fashion, requiring code to yield modular-arithmetic results in all cases where the result is coerced to a type that would render carry beyond the highest value bit irrelevant would have zero runtime cost.  I suspect that...

Comment: ...the standard would have made special provisions requiring modular arithmetic in such cases *except that it was something compilers naturally did anyway*.  A  slight variation of the proposed rule would be to say that if an expression involving those operators is coerced to an unsigned type no larger than `unsigned int`, the operands should be likewise coerced, though there might be some scenarios on weird architectures where that would "cost extra".  Standards like MIRSA favor doing everything using only fixed-sized types, but it's not possible to do this kind of math portably...

Comment: ...without making explicit use of the type `unsigned`.  While writing `x*=1u*x;` isn't the worst thing in the world, I see no benefit to saying that failure to do so should allow a compiler to regard `x == 65535` as dead code.  If the standard were changed so that every compiler must either follow modular-arithmetic rules in such cases or define `__STDC_NON_MODULAR_UNSIGNED_SHORT`, I would expect 99.44% of compilers written before 2010 would already have satisfied the requirement without having to do anything, and such a change would break *zero* application code.

Answer (score 13):

Signed integer overflow causes undefined behavior only when it occurs when evaluating intermediate results of arithmetic expressions, e.g. during binary mutiplication, unary decrement etc. Also, converting floating-point value to integer type causes undefined behavior if the value is out of range.

An overflowing *integral* conversion to signed type does not cause undefined behavior. Instead it produces implementation-defined result (with the possibility of an implementation-defined signal being raised).

Comment: Can you tell me how do you rely on it?

Answer (score 9):

According to C11, 6.3.1.3:

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if [...] the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Comment: @haccks: what do you mean? :-)

Comment: And presumably a program's behavior when it receives an "implementation-defined signal" is undefined. (The signal clause was added by C99; I don't know of any actual implementations tha to that, and I'm skeptical that it was a good idea.)

Comment: @KeithThompson In this case, I'm even happier, since the code I am writing with unsigned to signed conversion is written in C89.

Comment: @Kerre SB: That's true, but in n1256.pdf in 3.4.3 it says: "An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow". Would the standard say two different things on the same matter? Maybe my understand of overflow is incorrrect.

Comment: But if gcc warns about "overflow in implicit constant conversion", I think this *is* an overflow.

Comment: @user1042840: That example clause in 3.4.3 is non-normative (i.e. informative), see clause 6 in the Foreword section.  Besides, there's no overflow occurring here -- all you have is an integer literal (255, of type `int`, which does not overflow) being converted to type `char`.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: So is gcc warning misleading in this case?

Comment: @user1042840: It's only misleading if you expect the terminology to correlate precisely with the standard. On the other hand, since the compiler knows the concrete range of the target type, it is in a good position to tell you "this value is too large", which is essentially what it's doing.