# enums in c? Can they be used for storing

Tags: c, enums, enumeration

I am trying to find what will happen if I have 2 variables in enum
and I assign it a value.
I want a understanding on when i assign value to c_type which one gets used C1 or C2?

I have the following code:

```
typedef enum {
    C1 = 0,
    C2,
} c_type;

typedef struct A_a {
    c_type store;
} A;

FuncABC(int val)
{
    A a1;
    a1.store = val; /here store has C1 and C2, which one gets used here?
}
```

Please, let me know. I know the above code works logically in C.
But, want clarification on the assignment.

Comment: It will store whatever the value of `val` is.

Comment: I know that, but in what will it store?

Comment: it will store it in `a1.store`...?

Comment: In C, a1.store is basically an integer and your enums are essentially #defines with some extra compile time eye candy unless an enum value exceeds INTMAX (then it the smallest integer type that fits the max value) or you use a compiler specific "packed" attribute.  C++ does a little bit more with typedef'ed enums and would probably give a warning/error for the above assignment if a something passes a value other than 1 or 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are confusing is `a1.store` will store `C1` or `C2`.

**Actually**, `a1.store` could be `C1` or `C2` or `2` or `3` or `255` or whatever is the value of `val`.

Back to the C standard, an `enum` variable can store a value that is out of the range of values of the `enum` type.

You could also refer this [Enumeration object set to a value not equal to any of its respective enumeration constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683156/enumeration-object-set-to-a-value-not-equal-to-any-of-its-respective-enumeration)

Comment: And this is why it is not necessarily pointless to use `switch (a1.store) { case C1: …; case C2: …; default: …handle out of range…; }`.  Even though the `default` case should never be executed, it might if `val` is not a value from the enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behavior. The most likely result from your code is a crash, because you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Thanks sam for answering. Please, can you help me clarify on assignment operation here on enums.

Comment: This assignment operation is no different than any other assignment operation. It replaces the previous value of something, with a new value. That's it.

Comment: Yes but, in which enum? C1 or C2? as store as C1 and C2.

Comment: There's only one enumerated value. You are confusing enumeration with structures. An enumeration is an alias. Instead of saying that this integer's values can only be 0, 1, or 2, an enumeration says that this integer's value can only be C1, C2, or C3, for example. Using C1, or C2, or C3 is exactly the same as using the underlying integer value assigned to each enumeration.

Comment: Thanks, that was a dumb question ;). Got confused.

Comment: Note that the code in the question has been fixed since Sam posted his answer so that the correctly diagnosed 'undefined behaviour' is no longer a problem.