# implementation defined behaviour and reading unicode to buffer

Tags: c++, c

I have two questions, one small one, hence I will ask them together.
Is implementation defined behaviour as dangerous as undefined behaviour?

I read some unicode string from file using this code:

```
 char buff[1000];
 while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file) != NULL)
        printf("line: %s",buf);
```

I believe the unicode characters in the file where saved in UTF8 encoding.
But each UTF8 value was more than 128 when I checked. Nevertheless
the array is of `char` type as you can see (meaning range -127,128). 
But the string was correctly printed. What happened? Did I invoke UB?

Comment: char be signed or unsigned.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: didn't get your point but I think on my second question it is impl. defined behaviour (read somewhere)

Comment: The usual conversion of unsigned char to signed char is to subtract 256 from every value greater than 127. This preserves the bit pattern for twos-complement machines. As long as the bit pattern remains the same, you'll get the expected behavior. "Implementation defined" usually just reserves the right for a weird architecture to do things differently; you're very unlikely to run into weird architectures.

Answer (score 3):

When the standard states that something has implementation defined behavior, it means the compiler writer must document what will happen for that something. The behavior is **not** undefined, but the behavior may differ among implementations.

The signed-ness of `char` is one such example. It is implementation defined whether it is signed or unsigned, but the compiler implementation should document it (and usually, it will provide a switch to let you choose which way you want it).

Note that `char` is itself a type that is distinct from `signed char` and `unsigned char` (as opposed to `int` which is synonymous with `signed int`).

Cross references:
C.11: §6.2.5 ¶15 and C++.11: §3.9.1 ¶1.

Comment: so can we say impl defined behaviour is less dangerous than UB?

Comment: Yes, because the behavior is deterministic. But, the code that depends on implementation defined behavior is not maximally portable.

Comment: You read a byte into a char, and then you write a byte out as a char. What are you confused about?

Comment: the byte is unicode as I wrote and has value >128. My buffer is of char type. char has range: -127,128

Comment: That is what your implementation is choosing to represent your `char` as, but the value has a binary representation that translates to the correct unicode character. If you really care about seeing the "integral" values in your buffer, print them as unsigned, or store them in `uint8_t`.

Comment: the concern is char range is -127,128. But I write to it value which has value say 202 ..

Comment: The eight bit binary representation of 202 is 11001010, and this is what is stored in your char. This also represents the value -55 with a signed 8-bit `char`, but the binary representation is what is getting interpreted when it gets printed.

Comment: please look up on some places it is said this can be integer overflow and either impl defined behaviour or undefined behaviour

Comment: Signed integer overflow only happens when you do arithmetic. And you are not doing arithmetic.

Comment: @jxh: It's not that straightforward: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922601/is-char-foo-255-undefined-behavior-if-char-is-signed, you see? just I had bit different situation that is why I asked

Comment: If you feel that my answer is not helpful to you, I am happy to delete it, but I feel your question is unclear. You have shifted from why your `char` shows negative values to how values got stored into your buffer in the first place. Those are totally different questions. In any case, reading values from a file is different from assigning a literal value to a variable, so the issue you note does not apply. Note that the assignment of an out of range literal value requires "arithmetic" to get a sensible value assigned.

Answer (score 2):

To answer second question I think there is no UB with any code point represented in UTF-8 encoding, since referring to C99 latest draft `6.2.5`, p.3 (emphasis mine):

> An object declared as type `char` is large enough to store any member of
>   the basic execution character set. If a member of the basic execution
>   character set is stored in a `char` object, its value is guaranteed to
>   be nonnegative. If **any other character** is stored in a `char` object, the
>   resulting value is **implementation-defined** but shall be within the
>   range of values that can be represented in that type.

This might be useful to add that `fgets` function has prototype as:

> char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);

For example diacritic `ś` is encoded in UTF-8 as two bytes: `C5` (`197` in decimal, so it's outside `-128..127` range assuming signed variant of `char`) and `9B`. It's implementation-defined that `C5` is actually stored in a `char` object. As UTF-8 encoding "produces" bytes representation, there is no practical issue with storing value in any single-byte range.

---

For first question check: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).